Uncaught Type Error: Failed to resolve module specifier "module". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"
I have migrated my old angular version microfrontend project to update one with all dependency including NX.Now while running any remote app getting below issue in console
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "module". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
core.mjs:31064 Angular is running in development mode.
app.module.ts:18 ERROR ChunkLoadError
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (jsonp chunk loading:27:1)
    at ensure chunk:6:1
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (ensure chunk:5:1)
    at Object.loadChildren (app.module.ts:18:26)
    at loadChildren (router.mjs:4365:37)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadChildren (router.mjs:4340:40)
    at router.mjs:4029:46
    at doInnerSub (mergeInternals.js:19:19)
    at outerNext (mergeInternals.js:14:57)


please share the code of app.module.ts

here is my app.module.ts of a remote app
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([{
path: '',
loadChildren: () => import('./remote-entry/entry.module').then(m => m.RemoteEntryModule)
}], { initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking' }),
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
